# Windows 11 keyboard stuck in French

Tags: keyboard, windows-11

I have recently installed Windows 11. The keyboard is stuck in French mode. For example instead when I type a `?` it appears as `É` How do I make it revert to the standard English layout?

The "Windows Display Language" is set to English. I cannot find any language settings in the keyboard section of the control panel.

**This question is not a duplicate** The same question has been asked and answered *for other versions of Windows* however the solutions do not work in Windows 11 specifically as the settings have changed.

Comment: Provide a couple screenshots indicating which keyboard layouts you have installed, what locale your user profile is using, and the contents of `HKEY_USERS\.DEFAULT\Keyboard Layout\Preload` as an [edit] to your question.  This information will be necessary to answer your question.

Comment: The required information about the locale, for the user profile you are using, is contained within `Copy Settings` within Region which can be accessed from the Control Panel and/or Administrative language settings, within Settings